# 2:118 - what does the "abundantly clear signs" mean in this sura?

Tags: surat-al-baqarah

[2:118] In sura 2:118 it states "We have made Our signs abundantly clear for those who firmly believe"

What does **abundantly clear** mean here? What could be these signs?

Answer (score 0):

Asalamualaikum,

These signs are referred to the amazing creations of Allah such as Sun, Moon, Stars, The alternation of Day And Night, The Growth of a baby in the womb of a woman etc.

These are the signs which is referred in this Ayah and abundantly clear means that it will be clear for them which is true and it is up to them to choose the right path or wrong path. This is the speciality of a human being which makes them different from angels who have to obey Allah at all times and they have no other choice.

And Allah knows best.

May Allah Grant You Jannah.

Asalamualaikum.